# Sequence diagram with user interaction

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I am trying to draw a sequence diagram that requires user interaction. I tried to look for example online but I can't find it can anyone point me to the right direction?

I would like to draw a sequence on the ios application where I click a button that trigger the camera and wait for user to take the photo. Next this photo will be save to my database. My difficulty is how can I draw a sequence flow which ask for user input? Is there a controller that I need to add into my sequence diagram e.g iosManager for triggering the camera?

Comment: You could do that.  I don't know what "ask for user input" looks like, but you should be able to add an actor or object that accepts the request and interacts with the rest of your system.

Comment: Hi my intention for "ask for user input" is for the user to press the shuttle for camera.

Comment: Sequence diagrams need not be at that level of detail to communicate your intent.  Add a note if you must and get on with it.  UML can never be at the same level of detail as engineering drawings.  You're simply trying to communicate to stake holders.

Comment: I can't follow your sequence above: Click a button (where and which camera) and then "wait for user" which you explain as "press shutter of camera" (again which camera?). So you need to press two buttons to take a picture?

Comment: My intention was step1: click a button "complain" in my application. Step 2, it will trigger the phone's camera to be activated and wait for user to take a photo. Step 3, save it in my database and my application also upload the photo through facebook.

Answer (score 3):

I would likely model it like this:

[image]

`Complaint` is the screen from where you start your complaint. It triggers the camera which comes up with it's own `Camera` GUI that awaits the shutter click and returns after that. The `Camera` controller then saves the picture and returns to the `Complaint` screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could show the ViewController (Swift) and use an IBAction for the button press and an IBOutlet or whatever your choice for the prompt.  However, I think you should feel free to add an "actor" (same character as in the use case diagram) that receives the prompt and presses the camera button if that speaks better to you.